# JSF redirect in meta tag

Tags: java, html, jsf

i try to make a redirect in a html-page without hard-coded url.

**`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=#{testController.checkDatasourceFileExists()}" />`**

TestController is a ManagedBean. checkDatasourceFileExists() a method in that Bean, returns the filename of jsf-page as result if a file exists or not. if exists pageA if not pageB. But redirect is not working. only the url will change to:

**`http://localhost:8080/testapp/#{testController.checkDatasourceFileExists()}`**

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try using the tag, 
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=newpage.jsf" />` . If that works you can sort accordingly what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: hard-coded url like your answer is working. thats not the problem. i want not hard-coded url. redirect-url has to be the result of a method in the bean.

Comment: If you saw the URL generated for you, that itself is not giving enough information to go to the method, try calling javascript function and in that javascript function make a ajax call to the method which you want. <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=javascript:openIT();">

Comment: Thanks for your answere. But i think it is better to use spring webflow with decision-state. bcause first i dont want to use javascript, second if a file not exists an setup-flow has to start. Thats to realize the best way is spring webflow.

Answer (score -2):

try to get the contextpath and then your filename

```
<meta http-eqiv="refresh" content="0;url=#{request.contextPath}/#{testController.checkDatasourceFileExists()}" />
```